# visual basic 6 (vb6) meaning of codes

Tags: vb6

Im a beginner in coding, and Im stuck trying to understand this set of codes given to me by my professor. Here is the entire code of a form:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdSend_Click()
    Dim sIPAddress As String

    sIPAddress = Trim(txtIPAddress)

    If sIPAddress = "" Then Exit Sub

    With Winsock1
        .RemoteHost = sIPAddress
        .RemotePort = "1338"
        .SendData txtSendMessage
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    With Winsock1
        .Close
        .Protocol = sckUDPProtocol
        .Bind "1337"
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
    Winsock1.Close
End Sub

Private Sub Winsock1_DataArrival(ByVal bytesTotal As Long)
    Dim msg As String

    Winsock1.GetData msg, vbString
    txtReceiveMessage = msg & vbCrLf & txtReceiveMessage
End Sub
```

This is the codes I couldnt understand tho:

```
    With Winsock1
        .RemoteHost = sIPAddress
        .RemotePort = "1338"
        .SendData txtSendMessage
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    With Winsock1
        .Close
        .Protocol = sckUDPProtocol
        .Bind "1337"
    End With
End Sub
```

can anyone make me understand? a word for word meaning would be nicer to make my life easier when I encounter these codes for the next decades or two. thanks.

Comment: you will find all needed information inside the VB6 online help: [Visual Basic 6.0 Product Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338032%28VS.60%29.aspx). Please keep in mind: beginners of today are the experts of tomorrow ;)

Comment: If you are saying "codes" you are already horribly lost.

Comment: Some engineers who are non-software engineers may say "code" rather than "source code" (the programmer's term) but I don't know anyone who would say "codes" :)  At first I thought you meant like a set of numbers signifying something else...

Comment: you should ask your professor to explain this to you .. we have no idea which specific parts you don't understand, and it's too much to explain it all in detail .. your professor is the one you ask this

Answer (score 1):

When the form loads, Form_Load() is called and sets the Winsock's protocol to UDP and listens (bind) for input on port 1337.

There is a button (cmdSend) on the form.  When it's clicked, it sends the contents of the txtSendMessage textbox.